# How to fix "The aria-labelledby attribute must point to an element in the same document" error?

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I am facing this error while validating my web page thru W3C validator and I do not understand how to resolve this error. In my HTML I have used it in multiple s. Below is an example

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="undelivered-item-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="display: block;">
```

Please guide me on how do I fix this issue this as I am new to HTML5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message says that you are missing an element with `id="myModalLabel"`.

This element must contain a label for the `div` element.

If you don’t have the label as visible text, you should use [`aria-label`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#aria-label) instead.